# How the smart contract access the on-chain data?

Tags: tokens, oracles

For example, there is a ethereum smart contract on the ethereum, and there is a function in it which need the transaction data on the ethereum blockchain to make a judgement.

The question is: there any methods for ethereum smart contracts to access data on the ethereum blockchain?

Comment: The question is quite vague, can you add an example of what you need to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Please consider a contract like this: A gambling contract for 2 parities to guess a hash value of all the transactions in a specific future block, in this example, the contract have to access the transactions data in this specific block to compute the hash value and decide who is the winner. So my question is, how the contract could access these data? I know that by oracles, the contract could access off-chain data, but does the oracle also provides a way to access on-chain data? If so, is there any some else methods?

Comment: An oracle will always insert the data you want into the chain ( into a smart contract), i.e the hashes you want. After that you need to process the results.